# implement search like google search textbox

Tags: c#, ajax, search, .net-3.5

I need to implement the search (to show students name) similar like google suggests textbox.
I am using .NEt 3.5 . From client side i am planning to use updatepanel(Ajax search) and from backend using Linq to SQL. Once i fetch the data I am planning to store into cache to avoid multiple db calls based on the keyword. So if user type 'Joh' then cache will contain all the student name starts with 'Joh'. So if user types 'John' then from cache I will be able to filer it.

Is this the right approach or somebody can suggest me something else?

Comment: Your scenario is somewhat vague, but sounds acceptable. You'll have better luck here if you try this out and then come back with a specific question.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like a good idea.

jQuery UI has a widget called autocomplete that provides this functionality if you don't want to write it yourself. [link](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)